# how to put hide and unhide table row in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on a table which has some rows, I want to hide a selective row and unhide using a resettable button. how to achieve this?**strong text**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code.

Comment: please provide code snippet to understand your problem better way

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using HTML, jquery but they all work with div my code is pure HTML table so it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use accordion from [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion)
I have been using it for quite a while now it works fine.
Moreover, community support is good too.

Comment: Follow the link I gave you. there are many working examples
but to do so u have to convert your table with div and span structure